# ¿Cómo utilizar un arreglo de N tamaño en una estructura y usando punteros?

Tags: c++, array, punteros, estructuras

Mi problema a resolver es este:

Hacer una estructura llamada `alumno`, en la cual se tendrán los campos: nombre, edad, promedio y se pedirán datos al usuario de cuantos alumnos ingresara y comprobar cual de ellos tiene el mejor promedio e imprimirlo, usar punteros.

*Sólo me gustaría que me ayuden a resolver como crear un arreglo de tamaño N dado por el usuario usando punteros y estructuras*.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int nAlumnos;
cout<<"Cuantos alumnos deseas registrar? ";
cin>>nAlumnos;

struct Alumno {
    char nombre[30];
    int edad;
    float promedio;
}alumno[nAlumnos],*punteroAlumnos = alumno;
```

Comment: Las dos respuestas que hay son correctas, pero una posible alternativa sería decidir que hay un número máximo de alumnos y crear directamente un array de ese tamaño; tú solo usarias los primeros *nAlumnos* índices. Dicho esto, se tiene que consultar con el cliente/funcional (en el caso de un ejercicio de clase, el profesor) si es una restricción aceptable, y si el usuario pone un número mayor que ese máximo se le debería avisar y no dejarle continuar hasta que dé un número válido.

Comment: Y no olvides marcar como correcta la respuesta que te haya ayudado más.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esto es un VLA (Variable Length Array):

```
int nAlumnos;
cin>>nAlumnos;

Alumno alumno[nAlumnos]; // <<--- ESTO
```

Y es una característica **no soportada** por los diferentes estándares de C++. Esto quiere decir que, de funcionar, será gracias al compilador, no siendo una solución portable (te podría funcionar en el equipo de casa pero no en el de clase o al revés).

Para conseguir tu objetivo tienes que recurrir a la memoria dinámica, y para ello has de usar `new`:

```
Alumno * alumno = new Alumno[nAlumnos];
//     ^ ahora usamos un puntero

// ... usas alumno ...

delete[] alumno;
```

Nota que `new` tiene, básicamente, dos posibles usos: `new X` y `new X[]`. El primer caso te permite crear un único elemento, mientras que el segundo te permite crear una colección de elementos. A la hora de liberar la memoria hay que prestar especial atención a este detalle, ya que si hemos hecho la reserva con `new`, debemos usar `delete`, mientras que si usamos `new[]`, tendremos que liberar la memoria con `delete[]`

Answer (score 3):

> ¿Cómo crear un arreglo de tamaño N dado por el usuario usando punteros y estructuras?

Para crear un arreglo de tamaño decidido en tiempo de compilación, debes usar el operador `new[]`:

```
tipo *arreglo = new tipo[tamaño];
```

Es **vital** liberar la memoria cuando ya no se use con el operador `delete[]`:

```
delete[] arreglo;
```

Pero esto es tedioso y propenso a errores, olvida los arreglos y punteros, usa `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<Alumno> alumnos(nAlumnos);
```

Con esta opción no tienes que preocuparte de liberar memoria al final, por lo demás funciona exáctamente igual que un arreglo.

Ya que estamos redactando el código como [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), usa `std::string` para el nombre (en lugar de `char[30]`):

```
struct Alumno {
    std::string nombre;
    int edad;
    float promedio;
};
```

Y no uses `<stdlib.h>` ya que es una cabecera de [c](/questions/tagged/c).